# Displaying text or a popup in React Native relative to where the user has pressed

Tags: react-native

I have a requirement to display some text relative to where the user has pressed on the screen. When a user presses an element, some information about the element must be displayed, perhaps akin to a small popup. It is not possible to just replace the text of the element, as the user's finger would be covering it.

It is possible to get the co-ordinates of the press by using `TouchableOpacity` or one of the other Touchable components. However, I do not know how to handle the popup or to display text relative to these co-ordinates.

I don't think that `Modal` is the right solution here, because of the very specific size and positioning requirement.

Any help is very much appreciated.